# Remote Connection Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

How many remote connections can be made in windows server 2008. I want to work with 2 my friends on a same machine. But windows server 2008 forces, second user to logout when 3rd user try to login.

Comment: I've added the additional text from your other question and voted to close the other one as the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two if running the default "admin mode" for terminal services.

You can stretch it a couple ways, neither considered "legit" though...

1) Install VNC server and have third user use VNC client to connect.

2) Use the /admin switch with your RDP client to have the third user get the console.

*Just for suggesting those I'll probably have black helicopters over my house later today...*

Comment: I can't believe it took this long for someone to mention VNC...

Comment: A lot of people won't suggest VNC because if someone connects to the console to install an app(some will require this) they'll be contending with the VNC user.

Comment: Yes, we tend to exclusively use either RDP or VNC (depending on the server) for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

Without using terminal services and a license server I believe you're limited to 2 simultaneous users connecting to your server.  To get a third connection you need to use the console session which can be connected to by starting the rdp client from run with:

```
mstsc /console  (pre version 6, works with server 2003 not 2008)
mstsc /v addressOfServer /admin  (post version 6, server 2008)
```

You could use hyper-v or windows virtual server and each have your own instance to play with, or you could setup/buy the proper licensing to have all 3 of you connected at the same time.  Although having 3 people connected to a server isn't the best idea if you're all going to be installing software possibly at the same time anyway.

If you're students I would recommend the virtual server for each of you approach and look into getting licensing for it for free at [www.dreamspark.com](http://www.dreamspark.com)

Edit: After reading Sam's Answer and looking into it a bit more it looks like VNC is possibly the only way to connect to the console session on 2008.  I haven't tried myself to verify it, but the [impression I received from the technet blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/01/04/mstsc-exe-no-more-console-switch-in-rdc-6-1.aspx) is that the new /admin flag will connect you to an administrative session but not necessarily the console.

http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/01/04/mstsc-exe-no-more-console-switch-in-rdc-6-1.aspx

http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx

Comment: The console switch has been replaced by /admin in the new versions of the RDP client (6.0 or later)

Comment: I think its actually 6.1 or later (6.0 still had it with both working). I also think that it stops working with anything later than 2003/XP. The "session 0" cannot be connected to in vista/win7/server 2008.  Trying to find more on that since I don't have much for Server 2008 servers created yet.

Comment: sorry, your correct, it is 6.1 or later

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like by remote connections, you mean remote desktop. In this case, Remote Desktop in Administration mode is limited to 2 connections at a time. Should you want to use more than this, then you will need Application mode, which requires you to have a Terminal Services Licence server and a Client Access Licence for each user who wishes to connect to it, which cost money.

An unsupported work around to get 3 connections is to connect to the console, the actual view you get if you were to sit in front of the server and connect a monitor and keyboard. Using this method is not a fantastic idea as it will log off anyone who is actually accessing the server at the console. Should you wish to use this method the command to do so is:

```
mstsc /v addressOfServer /admin
```